# Two columun pdflatex output from memoir class book

Tags: lyx, memoir

What might cause the pdflatex output from a memoir class book to have two columns per page rather than one? Multiple columns can be used in some articles but not in a book.

Comment: Are you asking why this is an option? Or did you get a 2 column document that you don't want and want to know how to change it?

Comment: given the class has a `twocolumn` option, what answer do you want other than "the twocolumn option" or do I misunderstand the question?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Since this is a LyX question, I suspect it's because the two column setting is clicked in the Text Layout menu.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the LyX configuration is rather confusing and as Fran answers below the twocolumn switch is in a non obvious place. The main question would probably more be why a `memoir` document in LyX would start up in `twocolumn` mode in the first place

Comment: @daleif A new document in LyX  is always in one column with memoir and any other standard class. The user probably is using some template or selected the option    inadvertently.

Comment: @Fran I know, my LyX did that as well.

Answer (score 2):

You must set the `twocolumn` document class option in this way:

<kbd>Documents</kbd>
→ <kbd>Settings...</kbd>
→ → <kbd>Text Layout</kbd>
→ → → **☑ Two-column document**

[image]

Or alternatively in:

<kbd>Documents</kbd>
→ <kbd>Settings...</kbd>
→ → <kbd>Document Class</kbd>
→ → →  <kbd>Class option</kbd>
→ → → → <kbd>Custom:</kbd> 
 → Type here `twocolumn`

At the end, in the <kbd>View</kbd> → <kbd>☑ Code Preview Pane</kbd>  you must see the option `twocolumn` (of course, only once. Do  not set the same option in both places!).

[image: mwe2]

Beside this, in one column document you can also set:

<kbd>Documents</kbd>
→ <kbd>Settings...</kbd>
→ → <kbd>Modules</kbd>
→ → → <kbd>Multiple Columns</kbd>

To use the `multicol package via the <kbd>Insert</kbd>
 <kbd>Custom insets</kbd>
. This make a box where you can set an arbitrary number of columns (now you should have also this option in the <kbd>Insert</kbd> menu):

[image: mwe]

(Note: `\lipsum[1]` is only a command to type dummy text that only work if you add the package `lipsum` the in LaTeX preamble. If you have no idea what I'm telling you, just forget the Evil Red Text (ERT) box with this command, and replace it for some long "bla bla bla" typed manually to check the result.). The output must be some like this:

[image: mwe]